# attach .msg file to http request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a VSTO program the running on outlook.
The program adds button on ribbon in outlook
and when I click on the button the program downloads .MSG file and attach the file to WS in HTTP Post Request.

Because I do not want to trash the user's computer. I need an idea how to transfer the .MSG file without temporarily saving it to a folder on the user's computer

The program uses a MailItem SaveAs() function

```
MailItem mailItem = (selObject as MailItem);

mailItem.SaveAs(attchment.full_path, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any other method for extracting the message's byte array. So, saving the mail item to the disk is a proper way using OOM. You may also consider using `EWS` (see [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information) if you deal with Exchange Server or [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview).

Don't forget to remove the saved file on the disk as soon as it is transferred.

---

A possible solution is to forward mail items silently instead of uploading them via the POST request. In that case you will not have to deal with disk IO operations which could slow down the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook won't let you do that, but you can delete the MSG file as soon as you attach it to you HTTP request.

There is also no performance gain - chance are the file data will stay in the drive cache and might not even be written to the disk if it is quickly deleted; and as slow as files are, they are still orders of magnitude faster than network.